# Help, How do I interface this screen with an arduino?

Tags: arduino, connector, raspberry-pi, lcd, ribbon-cable

I have a very small LCD screen for my Arduino, it has a ribbon cable on it and I do not know how to connect it with an Arduino, it has a small piece of paper on it and that reads " OS096016PP08MB2B10 " not being stupid I did a google search on it and it came up with this as the data sheet, http://bit.ly/1M48HTo, it says it is a serial/parallel interface, and I cannot find a ribbon cable adapter for Arduino or Raspberry Pi,

All help is appreciated, thanks for even looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

The type of interface depends on bs1 and bs2, check the driver datasheet.

As for the physical connection, you'll have to get an adapter with the right socket that breaks the relevant connections out to 0.1" pins.

Now, for a practical solution: talk to the place where you got the display and ask about a suitable adapter pcb.
If that yields nothing, consider that similar displays ready-to-go, i.e. with adapter to 0.1" headers, can be had for ~1 USD shipped from a reseller on eBay.